# Covariance with C# Generics

Tags: c#, generics, covariance

Given an interface `IQuestion` and an implementation of that interface `AMQuestion`, suppose the following example:

```
List<AMQuestion> typed = new List<AMQuestion>();
IList<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed;
```

This example yields, as expected, a compile error saying the two are not of the same type. But it states an explicit conversion exists. So I change it to look like this:

```
List<AMQuestion> typed = new List<AMQuestion>();
IList<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed as IList<IQuestion>;
```

Which then compiles but, at run time, `nonTyped` is always null. If someone could explain two things:

- Why this doesn't work.
- How I can achieve the desired effect.

It would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The fact that `AMQuestion` implements the `IQuestion` interface does not translate into `List<AMQuestion>` deriving from `List<IQuestion>`.

Because this cast is illegal, your `as` operator returns `null`.

You must cast each item individually as such:

```
IList<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed.Cast<IQuestion>().ToList();
```

---

Regarding your comment, consider the following code, with the usual cliché animal examples:

```
//Lizard and Donkey inherit from Animal
List<Lizard> lizards = new List<Lizard> { new Lizard() };
List<Donkey> donkeys = new List<Donkey> { new Donkey() };

List<Animal> animals = lizards as List<Animal>; //let's pretend this doesn't return null
animals.Add(new Donkey()); //Reality unravels!
```

if we were allowed to cast `List<Lizard>` to a `List<Animal>`, then we could theoretically add a new `Donkey` to that list, which would break inheritance.

Comment: See, I always thought with generics that if I had a class declare `MyClass<T>` that `MyClass<IQuestion>` and `MyClass<AMQuestion>` were considered covariant and therefor convertable.

Comment: @WilliamCustode: Only if you can guarantee type safety. Rotem's edit demonstrated an example where you can pass in an incompatible type. However, you can "downgrade" some things: in this case you _could_ treat your `List<AMQuestion>` as an `IEnumerable<IQuestion>`. This is because `IEnumerable<IQuestion>` doesn't provide any mechanism to _change_ it so you're always guaranteed type safety. EDIT: This comes into play when you use the [`out`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx) and [`in`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469484.aspx) keywords.

Comment: I prefer to think of them as *traditional* rather than *clichéd*.

Comment: The fact that `List<AMQuestion>` does not implement `IList<IQuestion>` does not preclude the possibility of a class deriving from the aforementioned class and implementing the aforementioned interface.

Answer (score 12):

Why it doesn't work: `as` returns `null` if the value's dynamic type cannot be casted to the target type, and `List<AMQuestion>` cannot be casted to `IList<IQuestion>`.

But why can't it? Well, check it:

```
List<AMQuestion> typed = new List<AMQuestion>();
IList<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed as IList<IQuestion>;
nonTyped.Add(new OTQuestion());
AMQuestion whaaaat = typed[0];
```

`IList<IQuestion>` says "You can add any `IQuestion` to me". But that's a promise it couldn't keep if it were a `List<AMQuestion>`.

Now, if you didn't want to add anything, just view it as a collection of `IQuestion`-compatible things, then the best thing to do would be to cast it to an `IReadOnlyList<IQuestion>` with `List.AsReadOnly`. Since a read-only list can't have strange things added to it, it can be casted properly.

Comment: I appreciate the note about read only. If I only needed read access, I'd do that. Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that `List<AMQuestion>` cannot be cast to `IList<IQuestion>`, so using the `as` operator does not help. Explicit conversion in this case means to cast `AMQuestion` to `IQuestion`:

```
IList<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed.Cast<IQuestion>.ToList();
```

By the way, you have the term "Covariance" in your title. In `IList` the type is *not* covariant. This is exactly why the cast does not exist. The reason is that the `IList` interface has `T` in some parameteres *and* in some return values, so neither `in` nor `out` can be used for `T`. (@Sneftel has a nice example to show why this cast is not allowed.)

If you only need to read from the list, you can use `IEnumerable` instead:

```
IEnumerable<IQuestion> = typed;
```

This will work because `IEnumerable<out T>` has `out` defined, since you can't pass it a `T` as parameter. You should usually make the weakest "promise" possible in your code to keep it extensible.

Answer (score 3):

`IList<T>` is not covariant for `T`; it can't be, as the interface defines functions that take values of type `T` in an "input" position. However, `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant for `T`. If you can limit your type to `IEnumerable<T>`, you can do this:

```
List<AMQuestion> typed = new List<AMQuestion>();
IEnumerable<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed;
```

This does not do any conversions on the list.

The reason you cannot convert a `List<AMQuestion>` to a `List<IQuestion>` (assuming AMQuestion implements the interface) is that there would have to be several runtime checks on functions like `List<T>.Add`, to make sure you were really adding an `AMQuestion`.

Answer (score 2):

The "as" operator will always return null there as no valid cast exists - this is defined behavior. You have to convert or cast the list like this:

```
IList<IQuestion> nonTyped = typed.Cast<IQuestion>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 2):

A type with a generic type parameter can only be covariant if this generic type occurs only in read accesses and contravariant, if it occurs only in write accesses. `IList<T>` allows both, read and write access to values of type `T`, so it cannot be variant!

Let's assume that you were allowed to assign a `List<AMQuestion>` to a variable of type `IList<IQuestion>`. Now let’s implement a `class XYQuestion : IQuestion` and insert a value of that type into our `IList<IQuestion>`, which seems perfectly legal. This list still references a `List<AMQuestion>`, but we cannot insert a `XYQuestion` into a `List<AMQuestion>`! Therefore the two list types are not assignment compatible.

```
IList<IQuestion> list = new List<AMQuestion>(); // Not allowed!
list.Add(new XYQuestion()); // Uuups!
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `List<T>` is not a sealed class, it would be possible for a type to exist which would inherit from `List<AMQuestion>` and implement `IList<IQuestion>`.  Unless you implement such a type yourself, it's extremely unlikely that one will ever actually exist.  Nonetheless, it would be perfectly legitimate to say, e.g.

```
class SillyList : List<AMQuestion>, IList<IQuestion> { ... }
```

and explicitly implement all the type-specific members of `IList<IQuestion>`.  It would thus also be perfectly legitimate to say "If this variable holds a reference to an instance of a type derived from `List<AMQuestion>`, and if that instance's type also implements `IList<IQuestion>`, convert the reference to the latter type.